# How can I remove "days" when computing the difference between two dates?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pandas

When computing the difference between two dates using the following:

```
df_test['Difference'] = (df_test['First_Date'] - df_test['Second Date'])
```

I get a third column with "x Days".

How can I convert "x Days" into int "x". e.g., "50 days" into "50"?

Someone in a previous thread suggested to use:

```
df_test['Difference'] = (df_test['First_Date'] - df_test['Second Date']).dt.days
```

but using that I get an error of type:

> "'Series' object has no attribute 'dt"

How I can fix the issue please?

Comment: Did you convert your columns into a datetime?

Comment: Please add a data sample of your df. Dates have no "x Days" - that is a string output from somewhere. Read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: series.dt.days works fine for me if i subtract two date/datetime columns

Comment: `df_test['Difference'] = (df_test['First_Date'] - df_test['Second Date']).dt.days` works for me on python 3.6, pandas 0.22. Can you edit your post and show us an except of `df_test`, the `dtype`s of the columns and what version of `panda`s you are using?

Comment: I am using pandas version '0.14.1' and python version 2.7. sorrry what do you by "show us an except of df_test, the dtypes of the columns " ?

Answer (score 9):

If it is a string variable. then you can do the following and strip of the unwanted part. (say your variable is xDays)

```
df["xDays"] = df["xDays"].map(lambda x: x[:-5])
```

if it is a timedelta value you can do following

```
df["xDays"].dt.days
```

Comment: what is `sub(...)` of 2 strings? Considering the code `df_test['First_Date'].sub(df_test['Second Date'], axis=0)`in the question, how do you think it could be strings?

Answer (score 1):

By converting each of the subtraction variables to datetime, you can resolve the error you're getting. The following should work:

```py
df_test['Difference'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_test['First_Date']).dt.date - pd.to_datetime(df_test['Second Date']).dt.date).dt.days
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please edit your answer to format the python code correctly.  It would be great to show a small example to show that it works.

Answer (score 0):

If I stick to your code but fill in with made up data, this modification works for me. Basically you reassign the `df_test['Difference'].dt.days` to `df_test['Difference']` :

```
df_test=pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(['First_Date', 'Second_date'], [pd.date_range("2018-01-01",periods=10), pd.date_range("2017-01-01",periods=10)])))
df_test['Difference'] = df_test['First_Date'].sub(df_test['Second_date'], axis=0)
df_test['Difference']=df_test['Difference'].dt.days
```

Comment: This code works both for python 3.X and python 2.7 with pandas 0.20.3

Answer (score 0):

**Function**

```
def duration(diff):
    tsec = diff.total_seconds()
    hh = int(tsec//3600)
    mm = int((tsec%3600)//60)
    ss = int((tsec%3600)%60)
    return('{:02d}:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hh,mm,ss))
```

**Test Results:**

```
import datetime as dt

d1 = dt.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 10, 15, 12) - dt.datetime(2020, 10, 20,  8, 5, 12)
d2 = dt.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 10, 15, 12) - dt.datetime(2020, 10, 21,  8, 0,  0)
d3 = dt.datetime(2020, 10, 21, 10, 15, 12) - dt.datetime(2020, 10, 22, 10, 5,  0)
print(duration(d1))   #    26:10:00
print(duration(d2))   #    02:15:12
print(duration(d3))   #   -24:10:12
```

**Output**

```
 26:10:00
 02:15:12
-24:10:12
```